# Duplicated button doesn't work click();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var counter = 0;

  $("button").click(function() {
    $('body').append("<button>generate new element "+(counter++)+"</button>")
  });

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ru8jjzb/1/)

When you click duplicated button, it won't duplicate another button again besides the original button only works.

Why cannot listen this event to duplicated buttons?

**EDITED:**

```
//Click button event DELEGATION
$(document).on("click",".choice", function() {
  var userChoice = $(this).attr("value");
  //EXTERNAL SPAGUETTHI CODE
};
```

Need to grab "value" of this button when it's clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need delegation: catching the clicks on the parent but only those that were made on button elements. `$("button")` selects the existing buttons on the page, `$(document)` (you can replace `document` with your button container) will select the container and by using `$(document).click("button", ...)` you delegate the clicks on the buttons.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  $(document).click("button", function(e) {
    var value = $(e.target).attr("data-value"); // or .data("value")
    alert(value);
    $('body').append("<button data-value=\"" + ++counter + "\">generate new element " + counter + "</button>")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-value="initial-button">generate new element</button>
```

Here are some other similar answers I posted:

- [Direct and delegated events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22041545/1420197)
- [Delete dynamic elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33082173/1420197)
- [Function not working second time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20772868/1420197)

Comment: Do you have some alternatives of this snippet?

It forces to click a button without user input after of ajax content.

Comment: @Ivan What do you mean by *It forces to click a button without user input,*? By doing `click("button", fn)` you **append** a click handler, you do NOT click the button. To click the button you use `$("button").click()`.

Comment: I was going to use $(this); do you know how to select "button" instead of "document"?

Comment: @Ivan It's not clear to me what do you want to achieve—you said you want to catch the clicks on the new buttons. Isn't handling clicks on new buttons what you wanted?

Comment: I looked up about on(); it worked me but I need to know how to fix for $(this).attr; Updating my question, this comment cannot format code.

Comment: Done, can you check my edited question? I dont bother you anymore and I will accept your answer after of clearing my doubt, thanks.

Comment: @Ivan Ah, you have to use `event.target` instead of `this`. Because `this` will be the `document`/container. :)